# addition of hours in HH:MM using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple Time in HH:MM format in jquery. Like

```
 t1= '2:20';
 t2= '3:10';
 t3= '2:00';
 t4= '1:00';
 t5= '3:50';
 ............
```

How can we get addition of all infinite time in HH:MM format. For example sum of above time will be 12:20 .
I have tried following code for doing this calculation.

```
    $('.get_sum').each(function() {
            if (($(this).val())) {
                 sum = ($(this).val());
                 ms = new Date('Sep 24 2011 '+sum).getTime(); 
                sum += Number($(this).val());
            }
        });

function msToTime(s) {

  function addZ(n) {
    return (n<10? '0':'') + n;
  }

  var ms = s % 1000;
  s = (s - ms) / 1000;
  var secs = s % 60;
  s = (s - secs) / 60;
  var mins = s % 60;
  var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;

  return addZ(hrs) + ':' + addZ(mins) + ':' + addZ(secs) + '.' + ms;
}

alert(msToTime(sum));
```

any idea?

Comment: It's not really clear, but t1, t2 etc are variables, and they are probably strings, so it's supposed to be more like `var t1 = '2:20'`

Comment: why are you not splitting string to HH & MM and then count each HH & MM and then calculate total..?

Comment: i have tried that thing also but issue came on hh:mm like if it have above 60 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parse the strings as floats, and then add them up

```
var sum = [t1,t2,t3,t4,t5].map(function(x) {
    return parseFloat( x.replace(':','.') );
}).reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b; });
```

that leaves you with `11.8`, so we need to check if that last number is more than `.6` and if it is, add `1` to the total, subtract `.6` from the decimal and add the remainder

```
var left = (sum - parseInt(sum, 10)).toFixed(2);

if ( left >= 0.6 ) sum = parseInt( (sum += 1), 10 ) + parseFloat((left - 0.6).toFixed(2));
```

Now you have the number `12.2`, if you want `12:20` you parse it back to a string add pad it

```
var parts = sum.toString().split('.');

parts[1] = parts[1] < 10 ? parts[1] + '0' : parts[1];

sum = parts[0] + ':' + parts[1];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0p3ad7cw/1/) ([another one](http://jsfiddle.net/0p3ad7cw/2/))

Note the heavy use of parseFloat and toFixed, that's to avoid annoying errors with floating point numbers

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple way to count Hours and Minutes separately..

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin4dotnet/L3keu4ce/)
here is the code

```
var totalh =0;
var totalm =0;
$('.get_sum').each(function() {
            if (($(this).val())) {
                var h = parseInt(($(this).val()).split(':')[0]);
                var m = parseInt(($(this).val()).split(':')[1]);
                totalh += h;
                totalm += m;
            }
        });
totalh += Math.floor(totalm / 60);
totalm = totalm % 60;

$('.total').val((totalh < 10 ? '0' : '') + totalh.toString() + ':' + (totalm < 10 ? '0' : '') + totalm.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also way to do your job.

```
 var t1= '2:20'; 
 var t2= '3:10';
 var t3= '2:00';
 var t4= '1:00';
 var t5= '3:50';
 var strings=[];
 strings.push(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5);

 var i;
 var hourss=[];
 var minutess=[];

 for (i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
   var result= strings[i].split(':');
   hourss.push(result[0]);
   minutess.push(result[1]);
 }

 var minutes=0
 for (var i in minutess) {
       minutes = parseInt(minutess[i]) + minutes;
 }

 var realmin = minutes % 60
 var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60)    
 for (var i in hourss) {
       hours = parseInt(hourss[i]) + hours;
 }

 total=hours+':'+realmin;
 console.log(total);
```

Comment: Starting your answer with the words *"Not a good solution"* might just not be the most strategically wise move. ;) -- If it's not good, why post it at all? If you *know* it's not good, you also know how to improve it. Why didn't you? Or, if you *don't* know how to improve it, how do you know it's not good? :)

Comment: @Tomalak after posting my answer, i see Your's and adeneo's answer, that's why i edited my answer with this sentence "Not a good solution". :) :) hope you understand....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jQuery, but you can do it in JavaScript.

```
function totalTimes(times) {
    var totalM = times.map(function (hhmm) {
            var parts = hhmm.split(":");
            return (+parts[0] * 60) + (+parts[1]);
        }).reduce(function (m1, m2) {
            return m1 + m2;
        }, 0),
        h = Math.floor(totalM / 60),
        m = totalM % 60;

    return h + ':' + (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m;
}
```

usage:

```
console.log(totalTimes(["10:30", "9:45", "0:15"]));  // "20:30"
console.log(totalTimes(["23:00", "0:90"]));          // "24:30"
```

Of course you can use it from jQuery:

```
var times = $("div.time").map(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text());
    }).toArray();

$("#total").text(totalTimes(times));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have created simple loop for addition of more than one time hh:mm.

```
    var t1 = "2:20,";
        t1 += "3:10,";
        t1 += "2:00,";
        t1 += "1:00,";
        t1 += "3:50";
    var valNew=t1.split(',');//now split the time
    var hr1 = "00";
    var mnt1 = "00";
    var valNew1;
    var newval;
     for(var i=0;i<valNew.length;i++){
            valNew1=valNew[i].split(':');
            newval1 = parseFloat(valNew1[1])+parseFloat(mnt1);
            mnt1 = newval1;
            newval = parseFloat(valNew1[0])+parseFloat(hr1);
            hr1 = newval;
        }
//now finally we get all addition of time in second
        hr = Math.floor(newval1/60);
        mnt = newval1%60; 
        var hour = parseFloat(newval)+parseFloat(hr);
        alert(hour+':'+mnt);
//so we can calculate hh:mm
```